# Plotly dash template similar to shinydashboard

Tags: python, plotly-dash

For R Shiny, there are multiple very useful templates to start building your dashboard. Best known is the [shinydashboard package](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/), which makes use of a Bootstrap 3 template. I'm looking for a similar template or example as a starting point for creating a Dash Dashboard. There are lots of examples on [Dash webpage](https://dash.plot.ly/gallery), but none of these have navigation on the left pane.

### Question:

Is there a template for a Python Dash dashboard, which has navigation on the left pane and plots/filters in the right pane of the web page?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub [issue 44](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/44) has some good discussions about this topic, including:

- https://github.com/masdeseiscaracteres/dash-html-template

Also, this tutorial looks interesting, but it's not free:

- https://www.ftuforums.com/interactive-python-dashboards-with-plotly-and-dash-udemy-course-free-download/

Answer (score 0):

[Dash Bootstrap Components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/) is a component library that provides various components based on the Bootstrap design. The default look will have colors different from shinydashboard, but you can customize the look through additional CSS or by using one of the [third party themes](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/themes/).